# yii2 Getting array of data from one model and listing it in view of another

Tags: arrays, view, model, controller, yii2

In photo controller while listing photo I can get user data using function

```
    public function getUser()
    {
return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'uID']);
}
```

So when I'm listing some photo in view I can access users db using

```
$model->user['username']
```

But what if I have db of comments of this photo. and want to get all coments while listing photo.

what should I write in photos model to get all comments of this photo and how can I list them in view ?

in model I think I must use this

```
public function getComments()
{
    $modelComments = Comments::find()->where(['id'=>'commentID'])->all();
    return [array('modelComments' => $modelComments)];
}
```

If this is correct how can I output all comments in view of photo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `$model->user['username']` work at all? It should be `$model->user->username`.

Anyway set relation between photo and comments like with user but one-to-many.

```
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comments::className(), ['id' => 'commentID']);
}
```

Now when calling `$model->comments` you have got the array of all `Comments` models related to the photo.

Simpliest way of displaying them is to iterate over this array like:

```
foreach ($model->comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->content . '<br>';
    // assuming column name with actual comment is "content"
}
```

Comment: ok but can u write example of how I draw this array in photos view ?

Comment: @Bizley ```Does $model->user['username'] work at all? It should be $model->user->username.```. The answer is yes.  Anyway as addition to your answer: @David: after getting all the comments you only need to loop through the comments using e.g. ```foreach```.

Comment: @David I've added example

Comment: thnx a lot ! :)